# How to make a button that redirects you to a random page?

Tags: javascript, html, button

How to make a simple button saying "Next" that redirects you to a random page in the same tab of the browser? Like a refresh of the page but switching to another page. Just a simple button that changes the page randomly from a number of pages introduced there.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  There are many examples online of how to redirect the user in JavaScript.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is here to help with the code you wrote and not to write code for you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do this in three parts.

First, set up an array of websites to redirect to:

```
var arrayofsites = ["www.google.com", "www.facebook.com", "www.stackoverflow.com"];
```

Second, randomise which site is selected:

```
var randomsite = arrayofsites[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayofsites.length)];
```

Third, redirect the user to the site randomly chosen:

```
window.location.replace(randomsite);
```

Hope this helps.